# How to insert a row into SQL Server from Power Automate with dynamic table name?

Tags: power-automate

I have created a small test Power Flow that's manually triggered, accepts one input and inserts that into a SQL Server table using the SQL Server Connector `Insert row (V2)` and all is happy.

However, I need to be able to dynamically change the table name, because our corporate environment has separate Dev, QA, and Prod environments, and I need the same flow to work in any of the three environments by simply changing a PA Environment Variable.

When I modify the flow to use either a predeclared Variable (through Dynamic Content) or an Expression, the `Insert Row (V2)` suddenly demands a Row ID and also tells me that my data item is no longer available.

Here is the flow with a statically selected table that works just fine:
[image]

Here's what happens when I use a variable for the table name:
[image]

You can see that it now wants a row ID, but there *isn't* a row ID for a row I'm about to insert. I entered `1` for the RowID, but that'll only work on the very first insert (if it were to work at all). It also doesn't ask for data, so when I attempt a test run, it fails for lack of data.

Here's the actual error message that's returned:

> A value must be provided for item.
> clientRequestId: 7398bd76-75f7-41b1-b23d-8b9279737e4b

Is it possible to use a dynamic table name and if so, how do I go about doing so?

---

Taking [Skin's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77803341/2344413), I added a `Get Row V2` to my flow to get the JSON for my table:
[image]

I copied the JSON provided in the `OUTPUTS` section:
[image]

And pasted that into the `Row` parameter for the `Insert Row (V2)` step:
[image]

When I try to save the flow it tells me:
[image]

> Fix invalid expression(s) for the input
> parameter(s) of operation 'Insert_row_(V2)'.

It seems quite obvious to me that hard coding a value of `1` for the `"ID"` field is completely invalid since it's an `IDENTITY` column.

Do I need to drop the `"@odata.context"` and/or `"@odata.etag"` elements from the JSON? If so, that leaves me with just the column definitions (which I'd tried entering by hand) and it didn't like that, either.

---

Another attempt, with just columns defined in the `Row` field, leaving out the `IDENTITY` column:
[image]

Still gives me an error:
[image]

> The key didn't match any rows in the table.
> inner exception: The key didn't match any rows in the table.
> clientRequestId: 0064a03c-81c5-4928-b7fb-bf0f8cdc609a

Also fails if I hard-code a value into the `Rows` field instead of using the variable.

---

After finally groking the table naming issue and getting that sorted:
[image]

The run is still failing with exactly the same error:
[image]

The table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE testSchema1.Test1_DEV (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    DataField nvarchar(255)
    )
go
```

Yes, I'm 100% certain that the obfuscated server & database names are correct. I've confirmed them and I'm using the same connection that's working in another flow that's calling a stored proc (and is *not* using any dynamic table naming). What other obvious thing(s) am I missing?

---

I've attempted to simplify further. I removed the dynamic table name from the flow, and I recreated the table in the `[dbo]` schema to ensure that there weren't any rights/access issues.

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE Test1_DEV (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    DataField nvarchar(255)
    )
go
```

Then I modified the `Insert Row` step to explicitly select the table by name, instead of using any `Compose`, `Variable` or other possibly confounding factors, but I get an error upon selecting the table name:
[image]

I then deleted the `Insert Row` step from the flow and added a new, fresh one in. Now, it cannot find the table at all:
[image]

Even though the table is quite visible in SSMS:
[image]

Comment: The solution is not related to SQL Server, so I have removed the tag.

Comment: It's definitely related to the SQL Server connector, @DaleK, which is the part that's giving me problems.

Comment: No, it only wants the column values, as shown by my answer. Also, no, leave identity columns out. Once you do that it works, please mark my answer as correct. It’s not “advice”, it’s the answer to your question.

Comment: What do I specify for the IDENTITY column? If I put in `1` (which doesn't make sense) it tells me `The key didn't match an rows in the table`.  Same thing if I enter `""` for that column or if I delete the ID column completely.

Comment: Your answer, @Skin, shows `"ColumnName": "ColumnValue"`. I get the same error message when leaving the ID column out...

Comment: Look at your table name, it’s clearly wrong. It looks like you’re using an expression but you’ve entered it as a value.

Comment: I'll take a look at that when I'm back in the office on Monday. It does seem wrong though. Thanks!

Comment: Everywhere I have worked dev and test and prod tables have the same names - if you have control over that it would be well worth it to just not be adding `_DEV` to your development tables. In other words, a dev database is usually the same as a prod database - thats how you can write code and develop on it, and when your code is ready you deploy the same code to production.

Comment: That may be the case, @topsail. TBH, we're going to separate them out to have a DEV schema and PROD schema. However, that still means I need to dynamically identify which is which. (No, we're not able to spin up a new server to separate them, but that would _sill_ mean dynamically changing the connection as this PA app is migrated from version to version...)

Comment: "No, we're not able to spin up a new server to separate them" - you may want to at least keep the idea on the back burner. This is exactly how most it teams works (one server for dev, another for prod (perhaps also maybe another for test, or stage / release). Same table names, same schemas - all you have do is change a connection string, which is just configuration, much easier than trying to do all this with code that needs to manage environments using logic in the code.

Comment: Can you ask our corporate overlords on my behalf, then, please? Sadly, not an option at the moment, so I have to live within the current constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitely works, you're misreading the purpose of the `Row` parameter.

It accepts a JSON object that represents your table structure with values.

[image: PowerAutomate Flow]

[image: DB Result]

Comment: That makes sense. Well, sorta, if they wanted a JSON definition, it would have been nice if the field name were a little more obvious. I've made an attempt to follow your advice, please see updates to original question.

Comment: I'll certainly give you an up vote for guiding me in the right direction, but I still don't have a full answer yet.

Comment: See my other comment, your issue now looks to be elsewhere. The table name needs fixing up.

Comment: As Skin is saying, look at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWTxy.png - see how your table name is incorrect. You need to add your expression as an "Expression" and not as a string. You've entered the expression directly into the text field of your parameter. Do so via the Expression window.

Comment: I do see the issue, @SamNseir, however I did enter it via the Expression editor, not directly into the `Value` field. I'm not sure what the heck happened, but I'm working on fixing it up.

Comment: Adjustments made, but still non-functional. If I could entice either Skin or @SamNseir to take a look at the updated question...

Comment: try adding `"ID": null` to your JSON object. Failing that, try inserting a row with the table name selected from the drop down, and see if that works (for debugging).

Comment: @SamNseir, I did try the second option - see my most recent updates to the question. I'll give the `"ID": null` a shot to see if that works.

Comment: Tested with `"ID": null` yields: `Microsoft SQL: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.'. Was worth a shot...

Comment: And with `"ID" : 1`?

Comment: Giving this the check mark because it _is_ the correct answer. Again, another vague, misleading bit of info from Microsoft. The rest of the issues I've been having are described in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77827075/2344413).

Comment: I'd tried that earlier, @SamNseir. Didn't work then, won't work on an ongoing basis if I ever have more that one row in the table, anyway. Plus, it's an `IDENTITY` column and I don't have `IDENTITY INSERT` enabled...

Answer (score 0):

Having let this sit and stew in its own juices for a little bit, I changed the `Insert Row` to use the `Outputs` from the `Compose` statement.

I ran the query using a hard coded value for `"DataField"` in the JSON, and it succeeded! I then changed the `Insert Row` to use the `Variable` with the data entered when I run the flow in `test` mode, and that succeeded too! Note this is with the table with the most recent definition, in the default `dbo` schema.

I dropped the table, then added the schema & table (in the schema), updated the `Compose` to include the schema, and it fails again with the `key didn't match any rows` error.

I believe that this points to the fact that my rights for the schema I've created aren't set up correctly. So I'm going to have to look into this.

Thank you Microsoft for wasting 5 days of my life by issuing such a vague and useless error message.

Various web searching has indicated that this `key didn't match` error can be returned for *multiple* different issues. At least I'm not alone in the forehead-desk interface frustrations.