# How do I format the JSON for a SQL Insert in Power Automate?

Tags: json, power-automate

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77802692/2344413) contains the background of my situation. I got as far as knowing that I now need to put JSON in the field labeled `Row` in my `Insert Row (V2)` step of my Power Automate process to insert data. Unfortunately, I'm having issues figuring out how to format the JSON to get the data to actually insert.

In the answer (so far) to my original question, the example table has two text fields. My (test) table has an `IDENTITY` column and a text field:

```
CREATE TABLE testSchema1.Test1_DEV (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    DataField nvarchar(255)
    )
```

Obviously, I cannot specify the value to be put into the `[ID]` column like this:

```
{
  "ID": "1",
  "DataField": "20240112 090100"
}
```

[image: screenshot of Insert row (V2) settings with ID field defined]

That gives me an error when I attempt to execute it (which makes perfect sense - I don't have `IDENTITY INSERT` enabled for the table and won't).

> The key didn't match any rows in the table.
> inner exception: The key didn't match any rows in the table.
> clientRequestId: 7097d5d3-e4fb-4f5d-b111-6180f920b61b

[image: screen shot of error from Insert Row (v2) with the ID field defined]

The obvious thing to do, then, is to remove the `"ID"` field definition, like this:
[image: Screenshot of Insert row (V2) settings without ID field]

but that just gives me the same error:

> The key didn't match any rows in the table.
> inner exception: The key didn't match any rows in the table.
> clientRequestId: 3ad2bdae-7ac6-4009-8fc9-f3b07decebff

[image: screen shot of error from Insert Row (V2) without the ID field defined]

**How do I supply the proper JSON to feed data into a SQL table that has an `IDENTITY` column?**

Comment: You could try to *get* a row to see what keys there really are (according to PA).

Comment: I already did that, @ScottHunter. The results are in the other question. Fourth screen shot down.

Comment: @FreeMan this question really needs to be deleted.  Your original question has all of the context and has a valid, correct answer.  It's not worth opening another question for because the issue here is the same as in the other question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert a row into SQL Server from Power Automate with dynamic table name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77802692/how-to-insert-a-row-into-sql-server-from-power-automate-with-dynamic-table-name)

Comment: Please don't post a duplicate or follow-up to an un-answered question. Finish/continue there.